# Getting Groups Associated with Campaigns using REST API

Tags: api, groups, civicampaign, rest

CiviCampaign allows you to 'include group(s)' as a part of a Campaign. Is there a way to 'get' which groups have been associated for a given campaign ID using the REST API? The GET API for Campaign doesn't provide this information.

(Sample result below of a GET for Campaign)

```
{

"is_error": 0,
"version": 3,
"count": 1,
"id": 9,
"values": [
    {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "AAA",
        "title": "AAA",
        "start_date": "2020-10-19 13:35:00",
        "campaign_type_id": "5",
        "is_active": "1",
        "created_id": "202",
        "created_date": "2020-10-19 13:36:07",
        "last_modified_id": "202",
        "last_modified_date": "2020-10-19 13:36:07"
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download and install [Campaign Group API3](https://github.com/pradpnayak/campaigngroupapi) extension, this extension should provide Campaign Group api which you can either use as [chain api](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v3/chaining/) in Campaign api or you can use base as Campaign Group api and fetch all details of campaign by doing join on.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you so much. Quick question - can you tell me where in the your extension code can I find the logic get the 'group_type: Include'? Sorry I'm not familiar with how extensions are developed. Tried looking at the code but couldn't figure out.